# Getting "IndexError: list index out of range " error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, python-webbrowser

I am trying to get my followers and the followers of my followers to make a graph for a project
Below is the function that i get the error from. The error from the **followers[1].click()**.
I tried several things to fix this but nothing works.
To give you a better perspective. The python script automatically opens the google chrome, fills my credentials and navigates to my profile. Then it stuck there and throws the error.

```
    def get_my_followers(self, username):
        self.go_to_page("https://instagram.com/" + username + "/")
        time.sleep(5)
        my_followers_set = set()
        followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("-nal3")
        followers[1].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        initialise_vars = 'elem = document.getElementsByClassName("isgrP")[0]; followers = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("g47SY")[1].innerText); times = parseInt(followers * 0.14); followersInView1 = document.getElementsByClassName("FPmhX").length'
        initial_scroll = 'elem.scrollTop += 500'
        next_scroll = 'elem.scrollTop += 1500'

        with open('./jquery-3.3.1.min.js', 'r') as jquery_js:
            # 3) Read the jquery from a file
            jquery = jquery_js.read()
            # 4) Load jquery lib
            self.driver.execute_script(jquery)
            # scroll down the page
            self.driver.execute_script(initialise_vars)
            #self.driver.execute_script(scroll_followers)
            self.driver.execute_script(initial_scroll)
            time.sleep(3)

            next = True
            while(next):
                n_li_1 = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FPmhX"))
                self.driver.execute_script(next_scroll)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                n_li_2 = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FPmhX"))
                if(n_li_1 != n_li_2):
                    following = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Following')]")
                    for follow in following:
                        el = follow.find_element_by_xpath('../..')
                        el = el.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                        profile = el.get_attribute('href')
                        my_followers_set.add(profile)
                else:
                    next = False

            return list(my_followers_set)
```

This is the trace back of the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_my_followers.py", line 34, in <module>
    get_my_followers(config)
  File "get_my_followers.py", line 20, in get_my_followers
    my_followers = b.get_my_followers(username)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\testing\bot.py", line 74, in get_my_followers
    followers[1].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Complete `TraceBack` would help to undertand the problem...Pls, add complete error along with question

Comment: @Bhargav just updated with the traceback

Comment: Clearly the object `followers` is empty or has ONLY one element (if it is a list, set or dict). Debug the function `find_elements_by_class_name()` to find out the reason.

Comment: followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("-nal3") is the problem.  Best to check for size/count of the array before addressing an index as in followers[1].click()

Comment: @pcalkins i couldnt locate the problem